# Cannot route message for exchange 'bulk': Table empty or key no longer exists

Tags: redis, celery, ckan

I installed archiver extension (https://github.com/ckan/ckanext-archiver/projects) in my CKAN instance and I can't make it work through my entire catalog. The 'queuing' proccess (paster --plugin=ckanext-archiver archiver update --queue=bulk-c ) stops with the next message at some point of the execution (usually when it has proccessed less than 500 datasets -347 last time-):

```
kombu.exceptions.InconsistencyError:` 
Cannot route message for exchange 'bulk': Table empty or key no longer exists.
Probably the key ('_kombu.binding.bulk') has been removed from the Redis database.
```

I can't find anything related on Internet and I'm a little bit lost here. I'm running:

- ckan 2.5.2
- redis 2.10.1
- celery 3.1.25

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sorry, I've not seen this error in my experience with ckanext-archiver. Maybe the redis community can help.

Comment: @DRead yep, seems like a misunderstanding between redis and celery. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

similar issue here
https://github.com/celery/kombu/issues/1063

> This can happen if you set Redis to LRU mode or something similar.
>   Please configure Redis correctly and increase the memory of your Redis
>   instance.

Comment: I'm not with this project anymore but if I can test this I'll let you know. Thank you :)